# How to generate a random code for same email address after 20mins in php?

Tags: php

```
 $fetch=mysql_query("select time from code where user_email='$email'");
$db_time=mysql_fetch_array($fetch);

        $code= createRandomCode().time();
        $current_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
        echo "present time".$current_time;

        $time_string=strtotime($current_time); 
        //echo $time['time']."-".$time_string;

    $time_diff=($time_string - $db_time);
    echo $time_diff;
    //if time difference is less than 60,then its seconds
    if ($time_diff < 60) {
         $result=$time_diff . " seconds";
         echo $result;
    }
    //if time difference is greater than 60 and lesser than 60*60*60 ,then its minutes
    if (($time_diff > (60)) && ($time_diff < (60 * 60 * 60))) {
        $result=round($time_diff / (60 * 60)) . " minutes";
        echo $result;
    }

    //if time difference is greater than 60*60*60 and lesser than 60*60*60*24,then its hours
    if (($time_diff > (60 * 60 * 60)) && ($time_diff <= (60 * 60 * 60 * 24))) {
        $result=round($time_diff / (60 * 60 * 60)) . " hours";
        echo $result;
    }

    if ($time_diff > (60 * 60 * 60 * 24)) {
        $result=round($time_diff / (60 * 60 * 60 * 24)) . " days";
        echo $result;
    }
```

Actually, im trying to generate a random code for all users.But the struggle is when the user enters the email id, the code has been generated,even they click it after a second, the new code is generated.Now that is the problem im facing.

I want that the every old user get his code after 20mins only.Please do some favour.

Comment: Something truly random wont be so easily replicated again and again, otherwise its not random in the first place. I think you are better off trying a hashing algorithm and send them a hash. Otherwise if that is not secure, you could save the random string you generated for that specific user and send it again if they request again, that's not much safer either

Comment: Your code seems to have nothing to do with your question... What kind of random code do you want to create? does the user trigger this code generation? your code looks, as if it is just copied from another source...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send each user his code the best solution would be to use Cron Job (Scheduled Task).

This task could run every 2 minutes and send the code to all users which are valid for receiving a code.

You must create a task which will call your PHP script. An example:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://example.com/myscript.php >/dev/null
```

Here are some docs on Cron Job that will help you get started:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

If you choose this solution I would advice you to create a separate table which will be used only for storing [user_id, time_to_send_code].

Also don't forget to add indexes on your fields since it will be queried a lot.

Comment: Create a php script which queries all the users that are valid for receiving a code. Create a cron job which calls the previous script every 2 or 5 or 10 minutes. You already have the script created so you need to check the links I posted to get started with cron jobs.

Comment: I need better solution.give me a simple solution.